# Removed group as beta testers but their score still now showing up on leaderboard

Tags: android, google-play-games

I created a group for beta testers of my game, however as they are "normal" people (I mean, non technical guys) they want to appear on the leaderboard. I removed the Google Plus group from the list of beta tester, but they still are not showing up on leaderboard.

What do I have to do?